# Linking boost memory mapped files

Tags: c++, boost, linker, memory-mapped-files

I have a program that I started on linux Debian, so linking there was quite easy. All I had to do was the command lines:

```
LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_iostreams
```

Now I have to compile the same program on Windows. I downloaded boost version 1.58, and executed `bootstrap` then `bjam`. This compiled boost and created the `stage` folder which contained all the libraries.

Now I'm using the memory mapped file class `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source()`, so I'm getting multiple linking errors, from which I mention as an example:

```
FileCheck.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __cdecl boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::data(void)const " (?data@mapped_file_source@iostreams@boost@@QEBAPEBDXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl MD5FromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?MD5FromFile@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV12@@Z)
```

I tried to link to boost for this. So I added boost's path and :

```
LIBS += -L"X:/Path/to/boost/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib"
LIBS += -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-1_58    -llibboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-1_58
LIBS += -llibboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_58 -llibboost_iostreams-vc120-mt-gd-1_58
```

But still I get this error. Now I would like to point out that the compiler (VS2013) finds the lib files, but it's apparently not sufficient.

I also would like to mention that I use Boost::ASIO too and OpenSSL, but these link with no problems.

**Any idea how to link to boost memory mapped files?**

Thanks.

Comment: Sure about 32 or 64 bits library version ? if you build in 32 and the library is in 64 that can appear.
Have you check if the symbol is present in the library ?

Comment: Have fun with windows build. I'm waiting you here.

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat It's working now! You could post your suggestion as an answer and get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure about 32 or 64 bits library version ? if you build in 32 and the library is in 64 that can appear.